# Create a guest without any users

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been trying to create a Guest through a session in Rails without any User model or Devise etc, I just want a Guest which is created through one click.

The Guest then has a series of preferences steps (using the Wicked gem)

I've created a Guest model which simply creates a new guest upon the first click.

Each step of the preferences I'm trying to start the controller with:

```
 @guest = current_user
```

I've add the following code into my application controller for 'current_user'

```
 def current_user
    @_current_user ||= session[:current_user_id] &&
    Guest.find_by_id(session[:current_user_id])
 end
```

This is the action which creates the guest:

```
def start
    @guest = Guest.create
      if @guest.save
     session[:guest_id] = @guest.id
     redirect_to would_you_rather_path(:goalkeeper)
    end
 end
```

The problem I have is calling @guest = current_user is returning nil, which I believe means the current_user method is not right for my app.

I need the guest session to be called as the start of every step.

Grateful for any help/guidance

Thanks

Comment: Why do you set `session[:guest_id]` in `start` action and try to find `Guest` by `session[:current_user_id]` in `current_user` method?

Comment: you say it's returning nil - where is it doing that? in the console or the browser or test suite?  can you paste the full error messages?

Answer (score 1):

In `start` action you are setting `session[:guest_id]` and `current_user` you are trying to find through `session[:current_user_id]`. I will return `nil`.

Your `current_user` should be like:

```
def current_user
  @_current_user ||= Guest.find_by_id(session[:current_user_id]) if session[:current_user_id]
end
```

`start` should be like:

```
def start
    @guest = Guest.create
    if @guest.save
      session[:current_user_id] = @guest.id
      redirect_to would_you_rather_path(:goalkeeper)
    end
 end
```

One more thing, we should always try to use the default 7 action that rails provides, You should use `create` action instead of `start`.